# How to separate out all the methods, that return a SVGTransform object?

Tags: svg

Say for example I want to change the `transform` of an element, I know that I want to change the `SVGTransform` object of that element. But how do I get to know the possibilities(functions)for getting the `SVGTransform` object of an element?

I was searching searching back and forth with the MSDN method reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453568.aspx.

Is there any good and easy way?

Comment: Have you considered inserting a [animateTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/animateTransform) element?

Comment: Really i could like to do it with Dom scripting. So that it becomes easier, to do thinks on user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question, but to modify the `transform` attribute is quite simple, you can do it with jQuery or similar libraries, that is, you don't need specific SVG libs.

See my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxAWd/

For instance:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect transform="rotate(15)" id="r" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

The JS code:

```
$('#r').attr('transform', 'skewX(40)')
```

However if you need to create new SVG objects or to perform more complex tasks, I recommend you to use an specific SVG libs, just like: https://svgdotjs.github.io/ I've used it and It's great

You can do things like the following (Extracted code from the official site):

```
// create svg drawing
    var draw = SVG('drawing')

    // create image
    var image = draw.image('images/shade.jpg')
    image.size(600, 600).y(-150)

    // create text
    var text = draw.text('SVG.JS').move(300, 0)
    text.font({
      family: 'Source Sans Pro'
    , size: 180
    , anchor: 'middle'
    , leading: 1
    })

    // clip image with text
    image.clipWith(text)
```